# Chrome overriding placeholders based on name attribute?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Perhaps I've missed something here, but is Chrome by default adding placeholders - which override the ones I've provided - on purpose, based on name and ID attributes? I've tried with names including 'address' and 'email', and in both instances Chrome overrode my selections.

More importantly, is there a way to override this? I can see the value, per se, if there are no placeholders provided, but if they are, then that's a total pain.

```
<input type="text" name="emailaddress" placeholder="In Chrome, you won't see this" />
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3P5gx/3/. In Safari, etc., no problems. Chrome, no bueno.

Any ideas?

Comment: It works in chrome for me :/

Comment: What version are you running? I'm on 33.0.1750.152.

Comment: Works for me in `33.0.1750.154 m`. Did you accidentally click into the field and put a space into?

Comment: No, I mentioned it in a comment below. It's Chrome's Autofill 'feature' acting up. Didn't realize it puts its own placeholders in over the designated ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: This is in Google Chrome]

I can see it just fine in my browser.

Comment: Hrm. Do you have any idea what might be causing this? I don't have any extensions running that operate on forms.

Comment: You might want to make a fiddle showing your entire code for us to see.

Comment: I'm just prototyping something and noticed it - there was no JS, etc. operating on the page, but I figured it out in any case. Autofill in Chrome apparently puts in (for whatever reason??) placeholders, overriding what's in the code. Turned that off and it's fine. Seems odd to me, but OK.

Needed to bounce this off of someone else, make sure I wasn't going crazy. Thanks!